# A library for finding the points within X radial miles in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, math

Firstly, I'm not really looking for a mathematical solution to this problem, I'm looking for a library. This has been done a thousand times but my google-fu is failing.

Seconly, I have a rails 3 project (ruby 1.8.7 EE). Is there a ruby/rails library (gem) that will take in latitude and longitude (or alternatively a zip code) and determine what values, from a latitude/longitude set, are within X radial miles? Further, is there a way to run this at a lower level, for instance, as a performant SQL query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [geokit](http://geokit.rubyforge.org/) perhaps? If you want to do things in the database and your database is PostgreSQL, then you might be able to use [PostGIS](http://www.postgis.org/).

Comment: I looked at Geokit. It look decent but out-of-date on the rails support side. It's using Rails 2 finders like find(:all) which will soon be deprecated. I'm sure the source would reveal what I'm looking for but I would feel better about using an actively developed library. On, also, I'm on Heroku. I don't think it's possible to get PostGIS working on there.